# Asynchronous Processing in JBoss 6 ("Comet")

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jboss, asynchronous

**edit: Retagged as `tomcat`/`jboss`, since this could be a question about the Tomcat embedded inside JBoss 6, rather than JBoss itself**

I have an extremely simple servlet, which works on Glassfish v3. It uses Servlet 3.0 Asynchronous Processing. Here's a simplified version (which doesn't do much):

```
@WebServlet(asyncSupported=true)
public class SimpleServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        final AsyncContext ac = request.startAsync();
        ac.setTimeout(3000);
    }
}
```

On JBoss 6.0.0 **Milestone 2**, I get the following Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The servlet or filters that are being used
          by this request do not support async operation
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.startAsync(Request.java:3096)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.startAsync(Request.java:3090)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.startAsync(RequestFacade.java:990)
    at playcomet.SimpleServlet.doGet(SimpleServlet.java:18)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
    ...
```

Do I have to do anything special to enable Asynchronous Processing in JBoss 6? Or do I need an additional deployment descriptor? ...

Comment: @skaffman: Thanks for the hint with Tomcat! However, JBoss 6.0.0 Milestone 2 includes a completely new approach to asynchronous processing (Servlet 3.0 based), and AFAIK, this isn't availably in Tomcat releases yet - I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have web.xml deployed it with.. Just take that out.
structure should be

test.war

- WEB-INF/
- WEB-INF/classes/*.class
- WEB-INF/lib/*.jar

---

Your web.xml is overriding asyncSupported=true annotation and hence the error

Comment: Thanks for digging out my old question and for your answer! I usually can't just remove the web.xml, because I usually need it - so is there a way to achieve `asyncSupported=true` by modifying the web.xml somehow? I can't remember setting it explicitly to `false` in the web.xml. (I don't have my old project setup anymore, but I'm still interested.)

Comment: @Chris : you can still have web.xml but do not define the async servlet into it and let annotation kick in for this servlet. However I have not explored on possibility of asyncSupported=true attribute in web.xml